# Extract group title from one column of a pandas data frame as a separte column

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a pandas df like this:

```
0 'A'
1 'some text'
2 'more text'
3 'B'
4 'hello'
5 'hi'
```

and I also have a list = `['A', 'B']` containing the title of each group...

...and I want to transform the df to look like this:

```
0 'A' 'some text'
1 'A' 'more text'
2 'B' 'hello'
3 'B' 'hi'
```

In practice, I want to specify the group in a separate column.

Comment: are there quotes in you df or that is just a representation?

Comment: no quotes... sorry

Comment: and are all groups covered in the list or there can be lesser group in the list which you want to filter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `mask` followed by `ffill` to extract the group:

```
s = ~df['str'].isin(lst)

df['group'] = df['str'].mask(s).ffill()
df = df[s]
```

Output:

```
   idx        str group
1    1  some text     A
2    2  more text     A
4    4      hello     B
5    5         hi     B
```

Comment: Your solution works, thank you. I will mark it as answer. However, could you please refer to some exampls/docs to understand better the ~df[...] notation? In particular, I don't know how to use ~

Comment: `~` is negation operation, works on series. That line is actually `~(df['str'].isin(lst))`. You can print `df['str'].isin(lst)` and then `s` to see details.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your answer ;-)